# Default value for React Boostrap Option

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Im trying to set a value / placeholder for `Form.Control` but nothing works.

```
<Form.Row>
           <Form.Label>Select Operator:</Form.Label>
           <Form.Control as="select" value="" name="operator" onChange={this.handleChange} disabled={shouldDisable}>
           {
              operators.map(operator => {
                 return <option key={operator}>{operator}</option>
               })
         }
         </Form.Control>
 </Form.Row>
```

I want that the Default value will be `Choose Operator...` which cannot be selected (not trigger onChange) add `value`, `defaultValue`, `placeholder` didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading React-Bootstrap [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#form-control-props) there is no such possibility for that. My suggestion is to create a first `option` where its value is an empty string `''`. As well I would suggest to set the value property on `Form.Control` to follow React guidelines to have a controlled state:

```
<Form.Row>
    <Form.Label>Select Operator:</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control as="select" value={this.state.selectedOperator} name="operator" onChange={this.handleChange} disabled={shouldDisable}>
      <option key={'initial'} value="">Choose Operator...</option>
      {
        operators.map(operator => {
            return <option key={operator} value={operator}>{operator}</option>
          })
      }
    </Form.Control>
</Form.Row>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer - the problem that `Chooose Operator...` option is trigger onChange - how can i ignore this?

Comment: You can't run away from that sadly, but you can add a validator for your onChange based on the value. In this case something like `if (e.target.value === '') return`. This way, though onChange is triggered it won't perform any update state or any other logic you have on it.